# Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \ge 1, 0<y<\frac{1}{x^2}\}$. Show that $m_2(A) < \infty$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \ge 1, 0<y<\frac{1}{x^2}\}$. Show that $m_2(A) < \infty$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I now that the integral $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx = 1$ is it true that $m_2(A)$ is less than or equal to the Riemann integral?

Another approach would be to cover the set $A$. For this I considered $I_k=(k,k+\varepsilon) \times (0, \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2})$. Now $\ell(I_k) =\frac{k}{\varepsilon^2} + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ but the sum of these isn't very nice so I guess I need to find another cover?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cover it simply use rectangles of width $1$ and height of the maximum of the function for that inverval of length $1$. So you have
$$m_2(A) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are close. Measure of a set is equal to the Lebesgue integral of the constant function $1$ on that set. So the measure of your set is equal to the double integral $\iint\limits_A 1 dxdy$. Since the function has an absolutely convergent improper Riemann integral, the Lebesgue integral is equal to the improper Riemann integral here. And by Fubini's theorem the Riemann integral is indeed equal to $\int_1^\infty\int_0^{\frac{1}{x^2}}1dydx=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx$, which is a finite number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the cover $\cup [k, k+1] \times [0, \frac{1}{k^2}]$. The sum of these rectangle's measures is $\sum \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty$.

Comment: I guess I was first with that idea ;-)

Comment: Yeah, indeed :-(

Comment: No problem, bro. You can be first on my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262546/series-over-xya2bx-cy2-s

Comment: Is $k$ here a natural number?

Comment: @JimingLe It is a nonzero natural number.

Comment: Not only one, I guess. $k$ should run through all of those!